# RequireJS and AngularJS - Application module is being loaded at startup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have the following `main.js` that configures my `requirejs` framework:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular',
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

require(['angular'], function (angular) {
    console.log('Creating module');
    angular.module('myApp', []);
    console.log('Module created');
});
```

My `index.html` looks like the following:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
          <script data-main="main" src="lib/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         Hello, world!
    </body>
</html>
```

RequireJS is loading my dependencies just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="main" src="./main.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="lib/jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="angular" src="lib/angular.js">
```

The problem is that `angular` is throwing an error. These are my console logs:

```
> Creating module
> Module created
> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
         [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Why is `myApp` not available and why is it being instantiated? Nowhere else in my code I am loading my created `myApp` module.

Nevertheless, it should not throw any error, as this error happens **after** my module has been created, so it should instantiate it just fine.

What may be going on here?

Comment: Although the log's show the main.js is loaded before the error is thrown you can't assume this will be the case. Since RequireJS includes its dependencies with the 'async' attribute I would manually bootstrap Angular with `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])`

Comment: @ChristiaanScheermeijer This solves the issue if I want my application to automatically rescan for modules, but the startup error is still being shown

Comment: Did you remove the `ng-app="myApp"` from the html tag?